# Setting IBM MQ custom property in JMS doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

Tried setting an IBM MQ custom property in JMS while sending messages. It doesn't work.

I'm looking for an equivalent of the following in JMS/Apache camel.

```
mQMessage.setStringProperty( "customProperty", "123" );
```

Tried the following 3 options:

```
1) exchange.getIn().setHeader( "customProperty", "123" );
2) exchange.getIn().setProperty( "customProperty", "123" );
3) mQQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty( "customProperty", "123" );
```

The following code to read the property throws error because the property doesn't exist it seems.
mQMessage.getStringProperty( "messageGlobalSequenceNumber" )

throws the following error:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2471'.
        at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.getProperty(MQMessage.java:5694)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.getStringProperty(MQMessage.java:6949)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.getStringProperty(MQMessage.java:6925)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the property that you are trying to retrieve actually exists for that message?  Because Reason Code of 2471 (MQRC_PROPERTY_NOT_AVAILABLE) clearly says that the named property does not exist.

The correct way to create a message property in JMS (for IBM MQ) is as follows:

```
/**
 * Send a message to a queue.
 * @param session
 * @param myQ
 * @throws JMSException
 */
private void sendMsg(QueueSession session, Queue myQ) throws JMSException
{
   QueueSender sender = null;

   try
   {
      TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
      msg.setText("This is a test message.");
      msg.setStringProperty("MyProp01", "somevalue");

      sender = session.createSender(myQ);
      sender.send(msg);
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         if (sender != null)
            sender.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("sender.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Did you use an MQ tool to check the property values of the message?  I ran the above code then checked the message on the queue with [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) and here is a screen-shot:

[image]

Or a screen-shot of the opened selected message showing the Named Properties (aka message properties):

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm using Apache camel JMS without JNDI and MQ Explorer. From JMS it is being set and i can see it there but by the time it reaches MQ its gone. Saw some comment that i have to use camel jms header not camel header. So tried setting jmsComponent.setAllowAdditionalHeaders("customProp=12345"); This too didn't work, I'm running out of options to try. This post says there is some property but i can't figure out which one http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Add-custom-stringproperty-to-jms-message-td5751745.html

Comment: Does the message have any message properties when it is in an MQ queue?  If not, then what did you set TARGCLIENT to?  See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/465799

Comment: targetClient was set to 1, when i set to 0, i got the headers in MQHRF2 header. But i couldn't figure out how to set it in MQMD header. Tried to set jmsComponent.setDestinationResolver, still no luck.
         });

Comment: Tried to set the following in destination resolver
mqQueueSession.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
mqQueueSession.setBooleanProperty(WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
mqQueueSession.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT,WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT ;
mqQueueSession.setStringProperty("customProp", "abc");
return mqQueueSession.createQueue("queue:///" + destinationName + "?targetClient=1");

Comment: @Anu Best to edit and add details like that to your question.